# Jquery Selector for Element type and Class name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I have an element we'll call `selectedTable` that contains this `innerHtml`:

```
<TBODY>
    <TR>
        <TD></TD>
        <TD></TD>
        <TD class='ms-cal-nav-buttonsltr'></TD>
    </TR>
</TBODY>
```

I'm trying to use JQuery selectors to return the `<TD>` tag with the "ms-cal-nav-buttonsltr" class. I've found that `$(selectedTable).find("TD")` returns all the TD tags in the table as expected, but I'm wondering how I might go about combining the `TD` element selector with a class selector. I've tried `$(subnode).find("TD").find(".ms-cal-nav-buttonsltr")` and `$(subnode).find("TD .ms-cal-nav-buttonsltr")` to no avail, but those were just shots in the dark. What's the most efficient way to accomplish this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just concatenate the two:

```
$(selectedTable).find("td.ms-cal-nav-buttonsltr");
```

the selectors you tried were looking for a `.ms-cal-nav-buttonsltr` element underneath the `td`.

Answer (score 12):

```
$('td.ms-cal-nav-buttonsltr', selectedTable);
```

Comment: Is this the equivalent of what Dennis posted as a solution? Any pro's/con's to either method?

Comment: It's exactly the same thing. Personally I find it more readable, but that's it!